# When and how was the word 'Trekkie' coined?

Tags: star-trek, history-of, fandom

[What is the difference between a Trekker and a Trekkie?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/170224/what-is-the-difference-between-a-trekker-and-a-trekkie) extolls the difference, but I am wanting to know how the term was first used, or coined? It seems to go a long way back, further than I had assumed.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trekkie - 1967, apparently..

Comment: It also lacks any sources.

Comment: [This](https://web.archive.org/web/20070928071641/http://www.sciencefictionbuzz.com/startrekclassic.html) appears to be the source taken from [Arthur W. Saha's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_W._Saha) but that too is unsourced but provides a bit more information.

Comment: Term 'hippie' was common then. Likely based on that. No reference though.

Comment: Jeff Prucher's _Brave new words_ is a reasonable starting point for answering questions of this nature.

Answer (score 8):

Try as I might, it was very difficult to find a definitive source that absolutely confirms where the term Trekkie originated. According to Grinnell College, in an article [detailing the history of Trekkies](https://haenfler.sites.grinnell.edu/subcultures-and-scenes/trekkies/#:%7E:text=Trekkie%20is%20a%20term%20that,of%20admiration%20for%20the%20show.&text=It%20was%20not%20until%20several,form%20a%20stronger%20fan%20base.),

> Trekkie is a term that originated around 1970 as a way to describe fans of the TV show *Star Trek* who go above and beyond in their expression of their admiration for the show.

Wikitionary also states that the word originated in 1970 as a combination of the words trek and groupie. However, the website Fanlore states that the earliest usage of the term came in the 1968 essay [A Mid-Spring's Night's Dream, or, Journey to Backstage](https://fanlore.org/wiki/A_Mid-Spring%27s_Night%27s_Dream,_or,_Journey_to_Backstage) by Ruth Berman and Dorothy Jones, which described a group of fans meeting Mark Lenard, who played Sarek in *The Original Series*. Both women use the term once **(emphasis mine)**:

> [Ruth] I don't know about other people, but I'm afraid I was acting out of snobbery in cataloguing the roles I'd soon Mr. Lenard play when I sent him a fan letter—I'd wanted to make it clear I wasn't just a **trekkie** in love with Spock and therefore with all things Vulcan, especially Spock's father, but rather a sophisticated, mature admirer of good acting wherever it appears. Which I hope is true — but I'm in love with Sarek anyway.

> [Dorothy] His great, warm brown eyes are guaranteed to melt any **trekkie** into a helpless pool of protoplasm.

Finally, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trekkie) and a [few](https://web.archive.org/web/20070928071641/http://www.sciencefictionbuzz.com/startrekclassic.html) [other](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Arthur_W._Saha) [sites](http://askdefine.com/define/trekker) say that sci-fi editor Arthur Saha came up with the term after seeing a few *Star Trek* fans at the 25th World Science Fiction Convention wearing pointy ears. He apparently used this in a TV Guide interview with Pete Hamill, but I could not for the life of me find that interview. Therefore, the simple answer is **we don't know** but if anyone could track down that TV Guide, perhaps there would be a definitive answer.

Comment: +1 for contributing research to the question, if not a definitive answer. Partial answers need love too.